# Copy same content date fields values to separate content types by rules

Tags: entities, rules, datetime

What i want to do is this...

I have a content type (A) with two date fields (date_1 and date_2)
Then i have two more content types with existent date_1 field created.
(Must be this way)

Schema:
A: date_1 and date_2
B: date_1
C: date_1

An existing rule creates (every time a new node of content type A is created) a new content node of type B, copying the A:date_1 value to the B:date_1 value. That was easy... and it works just perfect.

Now, what i want to do is the (almost the) same with the content type C.
Except for the source field to be copied, that should be date_2

The rule should be something like this:
"Every time a node of content Type A is created:
Create a new node of content type C
and copy the date_2 value from node A, then paste it into the new entity field date_1...

Almost the same, except that when i want to select the source field, date_2 is not listed and i cant select him.

Is there any way to solve this?

Thanks a lot

Comment: field, date_2 is not listed because of a field configuration mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

field: date_2 is not listed because of a field configuration mismatch between both fields.
Everything MUST match between them.